# Fader Differ from Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I found this cool JQuery fader which does exactly what I wanted. The background fades, but when the transistion from image to image occurs all my other divs hide and then show basically.

**I want to make it so only the background image will fade and the divs won't essentially flicker.** I can produce a short video if need be.

HTML and JQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function fader() {
        $("img").first().appendTo('#wrap').fadeOut(3000);
        $("img").first().fadeIn(3000);      
        setTimeout(fader, 4200);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="fader();">
    <div id="wrap">
        <img src="images/Blue.png">
        <img src="images/Green.png">
        <img src="images/Orange.png">
        <img src="images/Pink.png">
        <img src="images/Purple.png">
        <img src="images/Red.png">
        <img src="images/Yellow.png">

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="sv_title">Title</div>
                <div id="sv_subtitle">Subtitle</div>
            </div>

            <div id="content_left">
                <div id="text">
                    Lorem ipsum
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="content_right">
                <div id="text">
                    Lorem ipsum 
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div id="footer">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html { overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; }

img{
position:absolute;
top:0;
display:none;
width:1920px;
height:1080px;
border: none;
}

body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#wrap { 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

/* End Setup */
/* Detail */

#wrapper {
height: 700px;
width: 900px;
opacity: 1.0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
} 

#header { 
height: 100px;
width: 900px;
background-color: #000000;
opacity: 0.7; 
}

#content_left {
height: 500px;
width: 445px;
background-color: #000000;
opacity: 0.7;
display: inline;
float: right;
margin-top: 10px;
}

#content_right {
height: 500px;
width: 445px;
background-color: #000000;
opacity: 0.7;
display: inline;
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
}

#footer {
height: 50px;
width: 900px;
background-color: #000000;
opacity: 0.7;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the job:

```
function fader() {
    $("#background img:first").appendTo('#background').fadeOut(3000);
    $("#background img:first").fadeIn(3000);
    setTimeout(fader, 4200);
}
```

and the fix in the html

```
<div id="wrap">
    <span id="background">
        <img src="images/Blue.png">
        <img src="images/Green.png">
        <img src="images/Orange.png">
        <img src="images/Pink.png">
        <img src="images/Purple.png">
        <img src="images/Red.png">
        <img src="images/Yellow.png">
    </span>

    <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- and the rest of the markup -->
```

it's not tested, I'm to lazy at the moment to create a fiddle and mock your images.

Comment: This would work +1. Changing the `img` `z-index` to -1 would also work.

Comment: {removed, because I was wrong; can't delete the comment}

Comment: @Yass yeah, but then you have to manage the images, the decrementing z-index and wich img is "first"; everything has pro's and con's